# Change device model on Android 10

Tags: android-10, builds, realme

I have Realme X2 (RMX1992) phone with Lineage OS 17.1 with root. I want to change my device model to Realme X2 Pro (RMX1931).

I have edited `build.prop` files in `/system` and `/vendor` folders with `ro.product.model=RMX1931` and also set the global device name as below:

```
adb shell settings put global device_name RMX1931
```

But still, my device is still recognized as RMX1992.

How to change the device model?

Comment: This might be because LineageOS have a init binary to read model from the bootloader, and you can't actually modify that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the method worked for me to change my phone model to Samsung Galaxy S10+

1. You need to have Magisk for root access
2. Install BusyBox and "MagiskHide Props Config" Magisk module and reboot the phone
3. Install the below terminal or any of your choice
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm
4. Open the terminal and type `props` to open MagiskHide Props Config and select option 5 to add/edit custom props values
5. `ro.product.model` and `ro.product.brand` values need to be changed to the desired phone model
6. Go back to the main menu and select option 3 to enable Device simulation for the values added in step 5 and then reboot the phone

After reboot, the phone model will change to the values added. You might also need to check build.prop file if any additional values to be added in the Props.

**Note:** Take a full backup of your phone before performing these steps in case of any issue occurs.