# How to change phone model for not get recognizing over apps like instagram

Tags: root-access, hardware

Where phone model props save on device?
When you login with another IP , apps like Instagram send an email which this email contain IP, Phone Model which had access to login.
How can i change phone model in Android?
I got root access.

Comment: There is a very similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/229405/2241

Comment: You can try this [Magisk module](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-magiskhide-props-config-safetynet-prop-edits-and-more-v5-4-0.3789228/)